# Perturbation Theory Applied to the Quantum Harmonic Oscillator

Tags: harmonic-oscillator, perturbation-theory

I am trying to compare the wave function obtained by exact method and by approximated method.
The potential is 
\begin{equation} V(x)=\frac{1}{2}m\omega^2+Ax\end{equation}
I found a solution but I am wondering what is the series development I have to do to go from function one to two.

Comment: can you share the reference from which you are taking this?

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA. why do you need it? I did all the problem by myself getting to equation 1 of the image. I do not know how to get the second. And it is well done because you get the same result as in approximated method.

Comment: @NelsonVanegasA.It is from "100 problemas de física cuántica" of Álvarez-Estrada.

Comment: Scans of text and mathematics are not considered appropriate on this site. Please use MathJax for your equations. BTW, this is an especially poor-quality scan, or perhaps some especially poor-quality book printing.

Comment: @G.Smith sorry. Will do next time.

Comment: Next time is NOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting $f(A)=\exp\left(-\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}\left(x+\frac{A}{m\omega^2}\right)^2\right)$, we expand as the instructions said, in powers of $A$:

$$f(A)=f(0)+\frac{df}{dA}(0)A+\frac{1}{2}\frac{d^2f}{dA^2}(0)A^2+...$$

The text only keeps the first two terms, but it appears to just be a normal Taylor series in $A$.

Comment: Oh! You saved me... Thanks! I was doing tons of stuff for x.

Comment: Wait but how is f(0)=1?

Comment: $f(0)=e^{-\frac{m\omega}{2\hbar}x^2}$, which has been factored out of the series in function two above.

Comment: Ok, that is right... my bad. Too late for me. Thanks once again!